# get value from a number named column

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to retrieve the value from a number-named column in `php`, no success so far.

Assuming I have these columns in a `msql` table

`id    name    someotherfield    200    404    500`

In `php` (`laravel` actually) I execute the query

```
SELECT * FROM table
```

I'm able to print the results, and everything is fine.

```
Log::debug($row)
```

Now, if I try to take a single value from the number named field, php fails and is always returned `empty`

This is what I tried (using object or array is the same for me):

```
$row->{200} // empty
$row[200]  // empty, of course

$field = 200;
$row[$field]; // empty
$row["$field"]; // empty
$row->$field // empty
```

Is there a way to do so?
Thanks.

Edit (my code):
don't worry about object or array, any solution is valid (as you can see the `100` field has `2` as value

PHP:

```
$row = \App\APIList::first();

Log::debug($row);
Log::debug("My value is: " . $row['100']);
Log::debug("My value is: " . $row->{'100'});
Log::debug("My value is: " . $row[100]);

echo "My value is: " . $row['100'] . "<br />";
echo "My value is: " . $row->{'100'} . "<br />";
echo "My value is: " . $row[100] . "<br />";
```

LOGS:

```
[2016-10-12 09:51:43] local.DEBUG:     {"id":1,"function_name":"xxx","verb":"POST","usage":"xxx","call_body":"xxx ","headers":null,"isReady":1,"used":0,"failures":0,"reason":null,"last_error":null,"100":2,"101":0,"200":0,"201":0,"202":0,"203":0,"204":0,"205":0,"206":0,"207":0,"300":0,"301":0,"302":0,"303":0,"304":0,"305":0,"306":0,"307":0,"308":0,"400":0,"401":0,"402":0,"403":0,"404":0,"405":0,"406":0,"407":0,"408":0,"409":0,"410":0,"411":0,"412":0,"413":0,"414":0,"415":0,"416":0,"417":0,"418":0,"422":0,"426":0,"449":0,"451":0,"500":0,"501":0,"502":0,"503":0,"504":0,"505":0,"509":0,"created_at":"2016-10-12 09:03:29","updated_at":null}  
[2016-10-12 09:51:43] local.DEBUG: My value is:   
[2016-10-12 09:51:43] local.DEBUG: My value is:   
[2016-10-12 09:51:43] local.DEBUG: My value is:
```

ECHO:

```
My value is: 
My value is: 
My value is:
```

edit 2:

php:

```
if ($row->{'100'} > 0) {
    Log::debug("Ok, got it");
} else {
    Log::debug("No way");
}
```

logs:

```
[2016-10-12 10:01:59] local.DEBUG: No way
```

Comment: Try `$row["200"]`

Comment: <?php
 $a=array("200"=>array("id"=>2,"name"=>"hello"));
 echo $a["200"]["id"];
?>    understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap the numeric value in quotes:

If `$row` is an array

`echo $row['200'];`

Treat it the same way you treat an associative array. The number 200 is no different from a string key 'foo' for example

And if it's an object:

`echo $row->{'200'};`

Comment: Not working, don't know if it's me, updating the main thread with my effective code

Comment: @GummaMocciaro Ok, so `$row` is an object. Just try `$row->{'100'}`, nothing else. This is the correct syntax, everything else will fail. See what happens

Comment: i did that as you can see in my logs/code (edited main thread)

Comment: @GummaMocciaro Yes indeed I saw that. What  I suggest is to remove all other logs besides this: `Log::debug("My value is: " . $row->{'100'});`

Comment: maybe is something related to the laravel model management that corrupts this kind of fields, i'm going crazy

Comment: @GummaMocciaro Check this line of your results:
`[2016-10-12 09:51:43] local.DEBUG:     {"id":1,"function_name":"xxx","verb":"POST","usage":"xxx","call_body":"xxx ","headers":null,"isReady":1,"used":0,"failures":0,"reason":null,"last_error":null,"100":2,"101":0,"200":0,"201":0,"202":0,"203":0,"204":0,"205":0,"206":0,"207":0,"300":0,"301":0,"302":0,"303":0,"304":0,"305":0,"306":0,"307":0,"308":0,"400":0,"401":0... ` I don't know how the Laravel Logger works but this looks like a JSON string maybe?

Comment: it's the way laravel logs stuff, i think all the problem is related to the laravel model, i'm trying to change the columns name so i can work around this problem, thanks for your time btw

Answer (score 0):

I opened a ticket to laravel on github and it seems to be a confirmed model management bug
https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/15869
https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15864#issuecomment-253232963